# Problem in LINQ query formation

Tags: c#-3.0

I have written

```
List<int> Uids = new List<int>();

    Uids = (from returnResultSet in ds.ToList()
                             from portfolioReturn in returnResultSet.Portfolios
                             from baseRecord in portfolioReturn.ChildData
                             select new int 
                             {
                                 id = baseRecord.Id
                             }).ToList<int>();
```

Getting error: **'int' does not contain a definition for 'id'**

what is the problem that i created?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<int> Uids = (from returnResultSet in ds.ToList()
                  from portfolioReturn in returnResultSet.Portfolios
                  from baseRecord in portfolioReturn.ChildData
                  select baseRecord.Id).ToList<int>();
```

Since you want to get a list of integers you can simply project the `Id` property from your query and then use the `ToList` extension method to buffer them into a `List<T>`.  As a side note, are you certain that a `List<T>` is the right type to use here?  You are forgoing the benefit of deferred execution and will not be able to stream these ids if you buffer them into a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to instantiate ints, setting an id property that doesn't exist. I think the following is what you need.

```
Uids = (from returnResultSet in ds.ToList()
                     from portfolioReturn in returnResultSet.Portfolios
                     from baseRecord in portfolioReturn.ChildData
                     select baseRecord.Id).ToList<int>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the: **select new int {}** part.

Try simply doing:

```
List<int> Uids = new List<int>();

Uids = (from returnResultSet in ds.ToList()
                         from portfolioReturn in returnResultSet.Portfolios
                         from baseRecord in portfolioReturn.ChildData
                         select baseRecord.Id
       )
       .ToList<int>();
```

select new {} syntax is for defining anonymous types (where use is limited to the same function scope).

Andrew.